# How can I define a sequence of recursive functions?

Tags: r, function, recursion

I tried to define the following function but failed. Any suggestions will be welcome.

```
H = list()
H[[1]] = function(x) 1
for(i in 2:4) H[[i]] = function(x) H[[i-1]](x)*x+1

> H
[[1]]
function (x) 
1
[[2]]
function (x) 
H[[i - 1]](x) * x + 1
[[3]]
function (x) 
H[[i - 1]](x) * x + 1
[[4]]
function (x) 
H[[i - 1]](x) * x + 1

> H[[1]](1)
 1  
> H[[2]](1)
 Too Deep Nesting
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining a set of functions recursively, define a single recursive function:

```
H <- function(x, n) {
  if (n == 1) 1 else H(x, n-1) * x + 1
}
```

Then, `H(x, n)` returns the same as your `H[[n]](x)`.

For completeness sake: your approach with the for loop does not work because each function depends on the specific value which was assigned to `i` at the moment the function was generated. 
At the end of the loop `i` is set to `4`. When you call `H[[2]](10)` R tries to compute `H[[i-1]](10) * 10 + 1 = H[[3]](10) * 3 + 1 = ...` which end in an infinite recursion.
Simply put, R does not remember that at the moment H[[2]] was defined `i` was equal to 2.